# Need help organizing my files and routes in Sinatra (moving old PHP site to Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Here is an example of how I would organize a site **clothes.com** in PHP:

```
index.php
style/
  style.css
men/
  index.php
  style/
    style.css
women/
  index.php
  style/
    style.css
```

How would you organize this same site in Sinatra? I'm confused because Sinatra doesn't seem to work much with "folder" structures, but you'd instead have the routes in the same file:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end

get 'men' do
  haml :men
end

get 'women' do
  haml :women
end
```

The problem is that everything just goes into the same "public" folder using this model. Is this the way its supposed to be organized?

How would you organize the stylesheet files, each different for index, men, women? Should they also go into the same "public" folder?

Comment: What's the difference between `men/index.php` and `women/index.php`? Are you sure that your PHP app was structured well to begin with?

Comment: @MladenJablanović The men's site is in men/index.php and the women's site in women/index.php (the generic main site is in the root index.php) I'm not sure if it's good, but that's how I've always done it. If you have ideas for better site organization in Sinatra feel free to post an critique/answer! :)

Comment: I was asking about the PHP code within the two files. Is the programming logic somehow different for men and women? (As opposed to having something like `index.php?category=men` and `index.php?category=women`) In order to get a good answer, you should describe your programming domain as good as possible.

Comment: @MladenJablanović Yes in my case, the men's site is substantially different from the women's site so I put them into two separate folders. Your ?category=men approach I have used if the sites are similar enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, coming from PHP *is* difficult.

There are some considerations about your site. Do you want to keep your old site strucure? If yes, you will have to use the same routes in Sinatra:

```
get '/index.php' do
  haml :index
end

get '/men/index.php' do
  haml :men
end

get '/women/index.php' do
  haml :women
end
```

Then you will also have to put your style files into the appropriate public folders:

```
/public
  /style
    style.css
  /men
    /style
      style.css
  /women
    /style
      style.css
```

Or you redirect from these old folders to just one folder if you want to keep your old style paths:

```
get '/men/stye/style.css' do
  redirect '/style/men_style.css'
end

fet '/women/style/style.css' do
  redirect '/style/men_style.css'
end
```

If you write all new haml templates you could put them into the `/public` folder directly.

Remember that when you call inside your haml template a style file via `style.css` (no path whatsoever) Sinatra will look in `/public/style.css` first before it checks for routes.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the following template for my sinatra projects: 
[Sinatra Github project template](https://github.com/oren/sinatra-template/)

EDIT: If you look in the routes folder, you'll see that he uses an init.rb file to require his other routes.

Also, I usually organize my css like this:

```
public/
    css/
         main.css
         men.css
         women.css
```

If the css folder has too many css files in it, I'll usually do something like this:

```
public/
    css/
        men/
            men.css
            more.css
            evenmore.css
        women/
            women.css
```